# VB Equivalent of the following code for threads

Tags: wpf, multithreading, c#-to-vb.net

What is the vb.net equivalent of the following c# code?

```
var thread = new Thread(() => 
    { 
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke ((Action)(() => new MySplashForm().Show())); 
        Dispatcher.Run(); 
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on the version of VB.Net.

### Version 10.0

```
Dim thread As New Thread(
  Sub() 
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke (
      Sub() 
        Dim form = new MySplashForm()
        form.Show()
      End Sub)
    Dispatcher.Run()
  End Sub)
```

### Version 9.0

```
Sub ShowForm() 
  Dim form = new MySplashForm()
  form.Show()
End Sub

Sub CreateForm()
  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(AddressOf ShowForm)
  Dispatcher.Run()
End Sub

Dim thread as New Thread(AddressOf CreateForm)
```

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to achieve though.  You are essentially creating another thread to asynchronously show a form but then immediately forcing the asynchronous operation.  It seems like it would be a lot easier to just asynchronously show via BeginInvoke and abandon the idea of creating another thread.

Comment: I am trying to get the splash screen to animate have the title of the application fly in etc.  I abandoned the idea once I couldnt get it work and needed to move on to other parts of the code.  I will give your code a try though. Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the C# code (and the VB.NET equivalents) will leak a thread. It starts the dispatcher by calling Run, but it never shuts it down.

Obviously, that assumes that you do actually start the thread at some point, which neither example does. You'd need the following code for the rest to be of any use:

```
thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
thread.Start()
```

In whatever code it is that tries to close your splash screen, you'll need something that gets hold of the dispatcher and shuts it down. E.g., your MySplashForm could have this:

```
Public Sub ShutdownSplashThread()
    Dispatcher.BeginInvokeShutdown(DispatcherPriority.Normal)
End Sub
```

That'll enable the thread that hosts the splash form to shut down properly. (And that'll have the side effect of closing the form too, so you don't need to do that.)